# Load a .txt file that contains 15 numbers, display them and remove duplicates VB.net

Tags: vb.net

As the title says additionally i have to next to them display a number at which point that number originally appeared in text file...so if a number appeared in First line of .txt file and tenth next to that output should be shown 1,10.

So far this is the code i have written.

Even writing solution in c# would be helpful because i can convert it.

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim FileReader As StreamReader
        Dim results As DialogResult
        Dim OpenFileDialog1 As New OpenFileDialog()
        results = OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog

        If results = DialogResult.OK Then
            FileReader = New StreamReader(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
            textBox1.Text = FileReader.ReadToEnd()
            FileReader.Close()

        End If

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could show us a sample of the file.

Comment: `
12
3
14
5
1
3
6
7
89
12
33
55
97
41
64
`

Basically from top to down

Comment: So each line has a value? As in line 1 contains 12, line 2 contains 3, etc.?

Comment: @John yep that is correct

Comment: So in your example, would the line numbers go 1 2 3 4 5 7, etc. missing 6 because the 6th line is a duplicate?

Comment: It would still display it but it would not display the second time it appears

Comment: Yeah, so would it be `1 12, 2 3, 3 14, 4 5, 5 1, --, 7 6, etc.`? Where `--` is excluded?

Comment: Yes but i would display it like 12 1, 3 2 etc...but it doesnt matter as long as i can get the display as youvewritten

Answer (score 1):

You can read a file into an array with:

```
Dim lines = IO.File.ReadAllLines("path")
```

You can iterate over the array with a For loop that knows the line number:

```
For lineNumber = 0 To lines.Length-1
```

You can create a `Dictionary(Of String, Integer)` that will store the value and the line number, but only if the value hasn't been seen before:

```
Dim d as New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)

For ....

  Dim line = lines(lineNumber)
  If Not d.ContainsKey(line) Then d(line) = lineNumber + 1 ' plus one because arrays number from 0 but you seem to want first line numbered as 1
```

The dictionary will, over the course of enumerating the loop, fill up with unique keys and the line number they were first seen

You can enumerate a dictionary and print it out:

```
For Each kvp as KeyValuePair in d

  'if the file first line was "10 then
  Console.WriteLine(kvp.Key) 'prints e.g. "10" 
  Console.WriteLine(kvp.Value) 'prints e.g. 1
```

---

I didn't write the code for you because it really seems like a homework, but give it a go - everything you need is here

---

ps; This whole thing can pretty much be done in one line using LINQ.. Something like:

```
IO.File.ReadAllLines(path) _
  .Select(Function(s,x) New With {.S = s, .X = x})
  .GroupBy(Function(w) w.S) _
  .Select(Function(g) $"{g.Key},{g.First()}")
```

But if this is homework, definitely don't hand this in!

Comment: "so if a number appeared in First line of .txt file and tenth next to that output should be shown 1,10."  Since we have REPEAT lines (possibly more than two, who knows?), wouldn't a `Dictionary(Of String, List(Of Integer))` be better so we can track ALL the lines where that value occurred?  So you'd have `unique line value` plus `list of all lines where unique line value occurred`.

Comment: I thought about mentioning it, but in the end my "answer the question that was asked" leanings overrode it. This question has a really kinda basic Computer Programming 101 "introduction to Dictionaries/HashWhatevers" feel to it, and when I'm providing homework pointers I tend to just keep it to what it is- I know if someone hands in something they don't understand then on their head be it, but having a Dictionary of Lists was just a bit too easy a stray into "i got someone else to write this" territory.. By staying away from it it doesn't risk being included because OP was unable to remove

Comment: All that said, the LINQ version conceptually does the equivalent of what you recommend, with the IGrouping so you could say that "it's in there for the curious" 

Answer (score 0):

Note that I'm treating the lines as strings, and not numbers. Hopefully this is OK for your purposes.

I would use a [`HashSet`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1?view=netcore-3.1) for this. This will allow you to quickly and easily check if a value has already been seen.

Next, we can introduce a variable to count the line number, and read the file line-by-line instead of all at once:

```
Dim line As String
Dim row as integer
Dim seenSet As New HashSet(Of string)()

do
    line = FileReader.ReadLine()
    if line is nothing then
        exit do
    end if

    row = row + 1

loop while not (line is nothing)
```

Now, we can add the `line` value to `seenSet` using `seenSet.Add(line)`. If it returns `true` then we have a new entry, if it returns `false` then it is one we have seen before:

```
// add this code inside the loop and directly below row = row + 1
if seenSet.Add(line) then
    Console.WriteLine(CStr(line) + " " + CStr(row))
end if
```

This will now print the value of the line, a space, and the row number.

[Try it online](https://rextester.com/SBZ65952)

If you need to build it into a single string to display in a textbox, we can introduce [`StringBuilder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder?view=netcore-3.1)

```
// Declare this before the loop (along with your other variables)
Dim result As New StringBuilder() 

// Replace Console.WriteLine
result.AppendLine(CStr(line) + " " + CStr(row))

// After the `loop while` line
textBox1.Text = result.ToString()
```

In the end you should get this:

```
Dim line As String
Dim row as integer
Dim seenSet As New HashSet(Of string)()
Dim result As New StringBuilder() 

do
    line = FileReader.ReadLine()
    if line is nothing then
        exit do
    end if

    row = row + 1
    if seenSet.Add(line) then
        result.AppendLine(CStr(line) + " " + CStr(row))
    end if

loop while not (line is nothing)
textBox1.Text = result.ToString()
```

[Try it online](https://rextester.com/FOP80135)